# How to use the start function in ts in R when date and time are included?

Tags: r, datetime, time-series

I am exporting data from a CSV file that has two columns. One has time and the other has power.
The time columns has the time in two different formats: mm-dd-yy hh:mm:ss AM and mm/dd/yy hh:mm:ss 24h format. I was trying to use ts(x, start = c(?,*), end = c(?,*)), where x is the timeseries and ? and * are the inputs I need to write to tell R where to start but I don't know what I should write.
Can someone help?

Comment: Normally ts is not used with date/time indexes.  Use zoo or xts.  You can use `read.csv.zoo`  and provide a function to the FUN argument to convert the index.

Comment: can you please elaborate more on this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
dates13 = power_use_replaced$ï..time
Ac13 = power_use_replaced$power
AC13 = ts(Ac13, frequency = 7, start = as.Date(dates13[1],format="%d-%m-%y"),
          end = as.Date(dates13[length(Ac13)],format="%d-%m-%y"))
```

This is one way. `power_use_replaced` is the data frame